# Immutability of Data transfer object in distributed systesms

Tags: java, spring, immutability, distributed

Should a simple data transfer objects (DTOs) or Value Objects (VOs) in a distributted Java systems been kept immutable?

Since there might be other instances in cloud used to get the shared object and manipulate.

Is there any runtime benefits creating all or most DTOs immutable?

Comment: A DTO in a distributed system isn't shared. Each "instance in cloud" has its own copy. This question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah, but whats the purpose of creating immutable objects using Builder pattern which is very much common pattern used in a distributed systems?

Comment: Immutable objects are easier to reason about. They might also be shared between threads inside a single JVM instance, in addition to being used only as a DTO. And the builder can validate the values before constructing the final object. Setters can't do that. Finally, DTOs are used to transfer a complex value, and values have no reason to be mutable. Making them immutable makes sure they aren't abused.